# How do you set the "Visible" property of a ASP.NET control from a Javascript function?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Bascially I want to know the best way to hide/show an ASP.NET control from a Javascript function.  I figured I would just access the control in Javascript using:

```
var theControl = document.getElementById("txtEditBox");
```

Then just set the control's Visible property to true/false.  It doesn't seem to be working, I can't seem to figure out how to set "Visible" to true/false.  How can I do that?  Also, is that the best way to hide/show a ASP.NET control from a Javascript function?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Why did everyone who responded get blasted with downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted a few of them because they were nothing more than late-comers repeating what was already said by a couple people, and they don't even care to answer all of the OP's questions but rather just fire a one-off answer. This question's answer is more complex than el.style.display = 'none'

Comment: The repeated answers were about a minute apart from one another.  We were all formulating our answers at the same time.

Comment: I understand that; SO has a feature that will let you know if someone else has already answered the question and allows you to then load those in the page. If someone sees that another has already provided the same answer, they should refrain from posting.

Comment: If that feature isn't working for whatever reason, the user can delete their post as soon as they post and notice 4 other people with the exact same answer, unless, of course, they were "first" (sort by oldest or newest and it will tell you who "won"). I just get sick of the clutter of dupe answers.

Comment: I downvoted 3 of the 8 answers (to his credit, one user deleted his post once he realized he was duplicating what many others had already mentioned). And again, the bigger issue for me is that people think their one line answer takes care of all of the OP's questions, when it does not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The "Visible" property of an ASP.NET control determines whether or not it will be rendered on the client (i.e. sent to the client). If it is false when the page is rendered, it will never arrive at the client.

So, you cannot, technically, set that property of the control.

That said, if the control *is* rendered on the client because the Visible property is true when the page is rendered, you can then hide it using javascript like this:

```
var theControl = document.getElementById("txtEditBox");
theControl.style.display = "none";

// to show it again:
theControl.style.display = "";
```

That assumes that the control's `id` attribute really is "txtEditBox" on the client and that it is already visible.

> Also, is that the best way to hide/show a ASP.NET control from a Javascript function?

There is not necessarily a "best" way, although one better approach is to use CSS class definitions:

```
.invisible { display: none; }
```

When you want to hide something, dynamically apply that class to the element; when you want to show it again, remove it. Note, I believe this will only work for elements whose `display` value starts off as `block`.

Comment: What are the other options for "style.display"?  How do I show it again?

Comment: No clue... but thanks for pointing out the insane duplication... I've deleted my copy :P

Answer (score 5):

instead of using visible, set its css to display:none

```
//css:
.invisible { display:none; }

//C#
txtEditBox.CssClass = 'invisible';
txtEditBox.CssClass = ''; // visible again

//javascript
document.getElementById('txtEditBox').className = 'invisible'
document.getElementById('txtEditBox').className = ''
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the style to "display: none".

```
var theControl = document.getElementById("<%= txtEditBox.ClientID %>");
theControl.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: That "txtEditBox.ClientID" is an important touch -- if it's runat="server", you'll need it every time. +1

Comment: You don't need it every time - you only need it if the control is not directly in a page that has no master page. If it is on a simple ASPX page, the ID will remain the same.

Comment: You are right... I am used to always using ASP.NET Master pages...+1

Comment: UserControls and Templated Controls also need you to use Control.ClientID. A Panel will add to the generated ID

Comment: Exactly - most people are writing non-trivial pages, and so your answer is worth noting.

Comment: A bit late, but I've just started on ASP.NET and this piece of JavaScript helped me out.  Thanks! +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't hide/ show the `ASP.NET` version of the control as that only exists in a server context. To use JavaScript you need to play with the controls style/ visibility state.

The only kind-of way to do it would be to wrap the control in an UpdatePanel and have something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsynchronousPostbackTrigger ControlID="button" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClick="toggle" Text="Click!" />
```

Then you need this in your code behind:

```
protected void toggle(object sender, EventArgs e){
  myTextBox.Visibility = !myTextBox.Visibility;
}
```

Now when you click the button an async postback occurs and it will refresh the UpdatePanel.

**Note:** This is not a *good* solution, as it'll be a very heavy AJAX request, because you need to submit the ViewState.

Also, it may not be 100% right, I did that from memory.

Comment: Holy crap - talk about going the long way home!

Comment: Hey, never said it was a GOOD solution, just an entirely .NET solution ;)

If you're not going to use display = "none" then you're a fool!

I just saw that every one of those solutions had been downvoted, thought maybe a pure ASP.NET solution was wanted :P

Comment: The scary thing is, you and I know this isn't really a good way to do it, but I am willing to bet someone will see your solution and think "Hey, that is a great way to do it - no JavaScript!!!" - those people scare me. :)

Comment: And then we submit to the daily wtf!

I should put that code on my blog as an example of what not to do.

Comment: I would concur - sometimes it is nice to have a bad example. Heck, I am sure some of my code from last week could serve as a bad example. Continually learning...

Answer (score 3):

This should hide the control:

```
theControl.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: What is this adding? Everyone else already repeated this, ad nauseum. This just adds more clutter to the page.

Comment: Not to mention, it doesn't even really answer all of his questions. Try formulating a longer, more thought-out response next time instead of a one-off hoping for reputation points.

Comment: Oh, you are a VB guy...that explains it. :P

Comment: Nothing like discouraging participation. Notice that in the time it took to fire off what I was hoping was a helpful clue in the right direction, a bunch of other people did the same. Next time I'll be sure to allow you to properly moderate all answers before trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the display property for this. But as Jason noted, this is a DHTML DOM (client-side) property that is completely independent from the ASP.NET (server-side) Visible property which controls rendering.

```
theControl.style.display = "none";
```

[Display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the display style property to 'none' (to hide) or `null` to show.

```
   var theControl = document.getElementById("txtEditBox");

   theControl.style.display = 'none';

   theControl.style.display = null;
```

Doing it the jQuery way:

```
   $('#txtEditBox').hide();

   $('#txtEditBox').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to use css:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to put your ASP control inside a div and set the property display to the div element.

```
<div id="divTest">            
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    SIN JQuery
    document.getElementById('divTest').style.display = "none";

    CON JQuery
    $('#divTest').hide();
</script>
```