# Hide asp.net Wizard next button in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to hide the Next button on my ASP.NET Wizard control using JavaScript.  Can anybody tell me if this is possible and post a javascript snippet on how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options here...

1. TemplatedWizardStep - that way you create the buttons yourself and can then use either the control name or a css class on the button to turn it on & off with javascript or jQuery.
2. use StartNextButtonStyle to set a css class on your next button so you can grab the button with jQuery.  Example of this one is below (I'm checking to see whether a checkbox is checked before enabling the button)

Wizard markup...

```
<asp:Wizard ... >
    <StartNextButtonStyle CssClass="StandardButton StartNextButton" />
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server" ID="AgreementStep" StepType="Start">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="AcceptAgreement" Text="I agree to the agreement terms." TextAlign="Left" onclick='EnableNextButton();' CssClass="NormalTextBox AcceptedAgreement" />
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

Javascript (using jQuery) to enable/disable the next button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function EnableNextButton() {

        var button = jQuery(".StartNextButton")
        var checkBox = jQuery(".AcceptedAgreement input:checkbox");

        if (checkBox.is(':checked'))
            button.removeAttr("disabled");
        else
            button.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }

</script>
```

Comment: I am interested in your example but am a noobie at jQuery.  When you are querying for the ".StartNextButton" text, does that search the CSS class names?

Comment: Yes, that's searching for the CSS class name.  In this case, i've used 2 class names just for the selectors in jquery so that I can find the controls no matter what they are named.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the answer from [question #267191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267191/how-do-you-set-the-visible-property-of-a-asp-net-control-from-a-javascript-func) to resolve your issue.

From the link (slightly modified):

```
var theControl = document.getElementById("btnNext");
theControl.style.display = "none";

// to show it again:
theControl.style.display = "";
```

Comment: I can hide a regular button, but it's the Wizard Next button that I can't figure out.  I can't seem to find the correct ID to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the server side code that will locate these controls.  You can take it from there...

I ran into this problem when I was trying to use a wizard for a checkout sequence.  I read a lot of these posts and they all have you jumping through a lot of hoops trying to find these buttons.  They tell you that you have to add custom step templates, trace the control etc...

The good news is that it's not nearly that difficult.  You don't need to use the custom templates..  Just drag a vanilla wizard control on the page, add your steps and this code works just fine.  I am using this code on a production app of mine.

```
Dim btnNext As Button = Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton")


Dim btnPrevious As Button = Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepPreviousButton")

btnNext.Visible = False



btnPrevious.Visible = False
```

Here is an example for the final step...(Note the different name for the finish button.... (Using their naming convention I at first thought it would be FinishFinishButton..) lol

```
Dim btnFinish As Button = Wizard1.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("FinishButton")

Dim btnPrevious As Button = Wizard1.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("FinishPreviousButton")


btnFinish.Visible = FalsebtnPrevious.Visible = False
```

I can't imagine why you would want to disable the Next button on the 1st panel but here is the code for that one as well.

```
Dim btnNext As Button = Wizard1.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StartNextButton")


btnNext.Visible = False
```