# getElementById().value Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing some simple code to change the visibility of an image when a button is clicked, but my `document.getElementById().value` is coming up as `undefined`. (I've tried replacing `.value` with `.display` - same result).

What could be the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function hideImage(imageId){
            document.getElementById(imageId).visibility="hidden";
        }
        function showImage(imageId){
            document.getElementById(imageId).visibility="visible";
        }
        function switchVis(imageId){
            var curVis = document.getElementById(imageId).value;
            if(document.getElementById(imageId).value=="hidden"){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="hidden";
                showImage(imageId);
            }
            else if(document.getElementById(imageId).value=="visible"){
                hideImage(imageId);
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="visible";
            }
            else{
                alert("Visibility Issue!\nVisibility value is " + curVis);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/k3.gif" id="k3"><p>
    <button onclick=switchVis('k3')>Visibility</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you get in curVis while debugging???did u debug your javascript code???

Comment: I've tried debugging using Chrome's developer tools. curVis comes back as undefined - it's part of the output in the alert box.

Comment: check the answer i  hv posted

Comment: The `value` property is used to get/set the value of **form** control elements. Images don't have a `value` property. You seem to be looking for `.style.visibility`.

Comment: I think there's a hole in my understanding. Why is curVis returning undefined? I've tried using .value and .style.visibility

Comment: Thanks Felix, but I'm still getting undefined. I feel like there's something simple I'm not quite understanding, as lots of people are giving the same advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply get `style` value by using `document.getElementById().value` . `getComputedStyle()` gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element. The returned style is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which can be used to get the value of your style. Try follwing code. It should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <script>
    function hideImage(imageId){
        document.getElementById(imageId).style.visibility="hidden";
    }
    function showImage(imageId){
        document.getElementById(imageId).style.visibility="visible";
    }
    function switchVis(imageId){
        var curVis = document.getElementById(imageId); //your element
        style = window.getComputedStyle(curVis); //returns CSSStyleDeclaration object
        curVis = style.getPropertyValue('visibility'); //now get your css value

        if(curVis=="hidden"){
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="visible";
            showImage(imageId);
        }
        else if(curVis=="visible"){
            hideImage(imageId);
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="hidden";
        }
        else{
            alert("Visibility Issue!\nVisibility value is " + curVis);
        }
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/k3.gif" id="k3" value="check"><p>
    <button onclick="switchVis('k3')">Visibility</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get visibility like that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/8ukWZ/)
So it's in `document.getElementById('myId').style.visibility`

//to make visible
`document.getElementById('myId').style.visibility='visible'`

//to make hidden
`document.getElementById('myId').style.visibility='hidden'`

Instead of value you used there's innerHTML. Value is for input elements.

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Jeff, what do you mean by same result?

Comment: I meant that curVis was still coming back as undefined.

Comment: If you refer to currVis that you have in your solution - there's no such thing as value for div elements. That's why it was undefined. I suggested you to use visibility property, and you can switch it by setting visible or hidden to element styles.

Answer (score 0):

try this

to show

```
  document.getElementById('k3').style.visibility='visible';
```

to hide

```
 document.getElementById('k3').style.display='none';
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267191/how-do-you-set-the-visible-property-of-a-asp-net-control-from-a-javascript-fun) for better idea

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the result is the same.

Comment: i have given a link to you in my post just go through that and implement in your code

Comment: Thanks again Anuj, but I still am not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add visibility property in img tag. 
   visibility="visible"

2.Also check visibility value with following.

document.getElementById(imageId).style.visibility=="visible"

1. Use same thing in hideImage and showImage function.

Comment: Thanks Nales - same result though.